# Return in an if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return

```
if(something == "") return;
```

Does it mean if something is " " aka empty, just exit the function?
I tried searching different answers. None of them explained what this piece of code does.

Comment: `" "` (with a blank) is not the same as `""` (without a blank)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Return inside and outside an If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282883/a-return-inside-and-outside-an-if-statement)

Comment: First of all, `==` is used for comparison, not `=`. Plus, to compare string value (not reference), you need to use `String#equals`.

Comment: `"None of them explained what this piece of code does."` - I wouldn't expect so, given that this code doesn't compile.  `String` and `boolean` are incompatible types.

Comment: I made a mistake it was ==

Comment: You should correct the code to show "==". In that case it looks like it would be saying if something is the same object as the empty string then return.

Comment: Did you try running a piece of code to see what would happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/4411297
Here is an answer that mentions Java String Comparisons. I'm not sure which data type "something" is, but I am assuming it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

`return` immeadiately exits the current function you're in.

That means that no code is executed after the return has been executed with one exception:

```
try {
    ...
    return;
} finally {
    // this code will be executed even if a return is called inside the 'try' block!
}
```

You can use `return;` (no value returned) when you want to exit a `void` method.

---

On a sidenote: [Don't compare strings with `==`. Compare strings with `.equals(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java).

---

Back to your original question: If the code was like this:

```
if (something.equals("")) return;
```

Then yes, it would mean that the method returns if 'something' is empty!

Comment: what can be the use for if(something == "") return; then? What I take from this is it's just like a comment

Comment: Check the link in my answer (thanks @Turing85) for details on the differences between `==` and `equals`. The code `something == ""` can evaluate to true under certain circumstances. But it almost never is the thing you want to do with strings!

Comment: @HelpMe123 I've updated my answer once more to get back to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors.

1. `=` doesn't check if something is equal. `=` assigns a value to a variable. You need to use `==` for primitive datatypes (like integer).
2. For strings you need to use `string.equals(anotherString)` to check if something is equal